# How to replace string after in a line in **C**

Tags: c

In C programming, I want to search in a file (See below), and check for a specific string (a particular logic block) and replace some bits in that logical block.
I can search a string/line and replace this with a new string. **But**, I want to search a string in a file and replace some string after number of lines/columns with another string. For example, I want to replace first 5 characters (00010) of line 7 after **.io_tile 1 0**.
Could someone please guide me how to do that?

```
.comment arachne-pnr 0.1+328+2 (git sha1 c40fb22, g++ 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 -O2)
.device 1k
.io_tile 1 0
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000100000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000100000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
.io_tile 2 0
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, are the sizes of the before and after strings equal?  If not, you need to rewrite the entire file following, and if growing, before substitution!

Second, after so many lines just means to read N lines before starting your search.  Lines suggests using a FILE* not an int fd, so:

```
int i ;
char buf[4096];

if ( NULL == freopen( "your file", "r", stdin )){
    perror( "open 'your file'" );
    exit( 1 );
}


for ( i = N ; i > 0 ; i-- ){
    if ( NULL == fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), stdin )){
        perror( "read 'your file'" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( NULL == strchr( buf, '\n' ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Line too long, make a bigger buffer!\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

Searching for string at beginning of line is a simple memcmp() (no null terminator needed).  Finding a string anywhere in a line is strstr().  Replacing a string of equal size is memcpy() or memmove() (no null terminator needed/written) (memmove() is only needed if overlap is a problem), fseek() back as much as was read past the write point (fseek() has a relative mode, as I recall) and fwrite() or fputs() the buffer from the written point at least as far as the modification.  If you want to do this more than once, you need to reset the file position using fseek() before resuming the fgets() loop.  Expanding the field requires rewriting the file first to slide the data up, then seeking back to the write point, and writing the new field.  Shrinking the field requires rewriting the rest of the file to slide the data down.

You can expand the buffer using a buffer made with malloc(), using realloc(), say 2x, and reading after the old data.

Comment: Thanks @David for the response. Yes the size before and after replacement would be the same. I just want to search some specific bits in an FPGA bitstream and flip them. The actual size of the file remains the same.

Comment: I once wrote a char string replace for a string anywhere in a file.  Of course, if the file has a checksum, that would be a problem.  I used it to change a well know default password of a trap door in an executable to something unlikely or impossible to be entered in, among other fun things!  Loop of memcmp() and on match memcpy().